# Looking to identify set from a part

Tags: set-identification

[image]Looking to identify set from the following part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's [Support Crane Stand Double](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2635#T=C) and Blue color was used in a single set - [Highway Construction (6600)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6600-2)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex!!! Greeting from Hong Kong, Florian